# Case Escalation rules : Dummy update on case updates the IsEscalation to false

Tags: escalation

We have an case escalation rule which fires on the below condition

```
AND(Account.Head_Segment__c = 'Liteal oluios',
    ISPICKVAL(Status,"Rejected"),
    Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c, 
    ISCHANGED(Status))
```

When the criteria gets matched the case goes into monitoring queue which is as expected.

But when we do an dummy update on the case the escalation rule get removed out from the queue

Any suggestions how to handle this...do you guys suspect that may be some workflow rule or process builder which is updating the isEscalation rule to false...

Please let me know if you have any hints to resolve this.

Comment: If you do a dummy update, then ISCHANGED(Status) will no longer be true, thus cancelling the escalated status.

Comment: but the status is not changed ...will it still set to isEscalation to false

Comment: Yes, because the record did not meet the criteria for the escalation rule.